# Transform to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and just wanted to know if there's a list comprehension that simplifies the function that I was creating, I tried but couldn't get the `vocabulary.lower()` without being outside and couldn't get the indexing right to the result list.

```
def encoder(sentence, vocabulary):
    voc = [x.lower() for x in vocabulary]
    result = [None] * len(vocabulary)
    for v in voc:
        result[voc.index(v)] = sentence.lower().split().count(v)
    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: What is this function supposed to actually be doing?

Comment: Oh I get it now, it returns the count for each vocabulary word based on number of times it appears in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

As you need, it'll be a `dict-comprehension` in your case : `{k:v for ...}`. Also `enumerate()` generates the elements of the given iterable and the index at the same time, so you don't need `voc.index(v)`

```
def encoder(sentence, vocabulary):
    voc = [x.lower() for x in vocabulary]
    words = sentence.lower().split()
    return {idx : words.count(v) for idx, v in enumerate(voc)}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for the quick reply! The exercise I was working with just requested for the list instead of the whole dictionary but obviously that way it is even better!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that since you're building your list as you iterate over `vocabulary` the indices match without you having to do that tricky `.index()` business.

```
from typing import Iterable, List


def word_frequency(sentence: str, vocabulary: Iterable[str]) -> List[int]:
    """Returns the number of times each vocabulary word is used in the sentence."""
    return [
        sentence.lower().split().count(word.lower())
        for word in vocabulary
    ]
```

You might also be interested in the `Counter` class, which you can use for a very similar purpose by doing something like:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(sentence.lower().split()))
```

Comment: I haven't studied Classes yet but it's an excellent way to start looking at it! Thank you very much for your time!